# intellij debugger does not recognize code changes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly, hotswap

I am debugging java class of web application. When I change a string or add simple code line like printing string in the console (System.out.print.n("changes") these changes have no affect. also when I click str+shift+f9. Even when I restart wildfly server I still can not see my changes.

Only when when I delete target and clean install my project and start wildfly then my chnages have affect.

hotswap is configured like this
[image]

I am using exploded artifact configuration in customized standalone-full-myproject.xml file:

```
 <deployment name="myproject.war" runtime-name="myproject.war">
            <fs-exploded path="C:\work\workspace\project-parent\project-backend\resources\system\..\..\..\project-frontend\target\war"/>
        </deployment>
```

and run it from the idea like this:
[image]

startup/connection tab:
[image]

Deployment tab
[image]
Any Idea?

thank you

Comment: Does Ctrl-F9 help?

Comment: Use exploded artifact and Update action per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html. Double check the files are changed in the artifact output directory.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: I am already using exloded war folder configured in standalone.xml. I ahve updated my question

Comment: Don't change any XML files manually, IDE will do it for you. Make sure the artifact is built by the IDE. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: when i click ctr-f9 i get the msg: loaded classes are up to date. nothing to reload. still older code is there

Comment: @CrazyCoder: actually we have customized standalone-full-myproject.xml and we run it from the ide. I have added screenshot to the question

Comment: Deployment of the artifact has to be done via the Deployment tab, it will modify the XML automatically. If you build the artifacts externally or modify the XML file manually, Update action will not work.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have to use the customized file otherwise the application does not start as the customized file contains additionals stuff required for the application. I have added screenshots for deployment and startup/connection tabs

Comment: This will not work for Update classes and resources. Artifact needs to be built directly by the IDE.

Comment: @CrazyCoder How to build artifacts by IDE? When I click the + on Deployement tab, I can see only "External Source..." which can be added. No artifacts

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.